# Cannot scan list of numbers into list of tuples

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to scan a list of lists and return a list of 2-tuples, the first item the sublist, and the second the sum of the sublist. Here is the function:

```
listToTups :: (Num a) => [[a]] -> [([a], a)]
listToTups x = scanl (\acc item -> (item, sum item) : acc) [] x
```

When I try to compile I get this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `([a], a)' with actual type `[a0]'
    In the second argument of `scanl', namely `[]'
    In the expression:
      scanl (\ acc item -> (item, sum item) : acc) [] x
```

This doesn't make sense since the lambda function is clearly returning a list of tuples. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

This is what I'm trying to do. Given a list of [Int], I want to return a list of 2-tuples, the first element being the sublist itself, and the second being the sum. So something like:

```
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]] -> [([1,2,3], 6), ([4,5,6], 15)]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Per @melpomene's suggestion, perhaps you want `listToTups = map (id &&& sum)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since

```
scanl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]
```

and you demand that

```
scanl _ _ :: Num c => [[c]] -> [([c], c)]
```

we conclude that `b` must be `([c], c)` (by unifying the return type of `scanl` and the return type of the supplied type signature). However, you also demand that

```
scanl _ []
```

be well-typed, from which we conclude that `b` must be `[d]` (by unifying the type of the second argument to `scanl` and the type of `[]`). These two constraints -- that `b` be a tuple type and that `b` be a list type -- are not compatible.

Your description of what you're trying to achieve isn't so clear to me, and it's not immediately obvious from the code, either, so I can't offer much advice on how to fix it. I can only hope that the above description of the problem is clear enough that it helps you see a solution for yourself.

Comment: That should probably be `foldl`, not `scanl`.

Comment: @melpomene Well, that type-checks at least! So I'd say that's a pretty good guess.

Comment: Well, and the `foldl` should be a `foldr`, and then the whole thing turns into a `map`. :-)

Comment: I understand my mistake now. I should have used the `map` function instead. What is scan actually used for in the real world?